# excel recovery error after running python script

Tags: python, excel, recovery

I am running a python script to paste some value from a notepad to excel.
The address part of the excel should be in different rows like this:
[Python Excel Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bO9CU.png)

But this does not print the value in excel like above. Instead it prints as this:
[Python Excel Error 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QLTbX.png)

Below is the code:
**

```
**# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
"""
Created on Fri Nov  2 12:00:36 2018
@author: yy
"""
import re
import openpyxl
name = "Default"
i = 2
add = ""
text = [line.rstrip('\n') for line in open(r'''C:\Users\xxx\Desktop\yy files\EDF Energy\NewNote.txt''', "r")]
book = openpyxl.load_workbook(r'C:\Users\xxx\Desktop\yy files\test_value.xlsx')
sheet = book['Sheet1']
#ws = book.worksheets[0]
        #Retriving Account Number
for line in text: 
    x = re.findall('(\d{3}[\s]\d{3}[\s]\d{3}[\s]\d{3})', line)
    if len(x) != 0: 
        accno= (", ".join(x))
        y= accno.replace(" ","")
        accno=int(y)
        print("account number, y ",accno, y)
#Retriving Name      
    if "Hello" in line:
        name = line[5:]
        name= name.replace(",","")
        name= name.replace("-","")
        print("name ",name)
        #sheet['B2']=name
 #Retriving outstanding Balance
    if "projection:" in line:
        z = re.findall(r'\d+[.]\d+',line)
        print("z ",z)
        accbal = (", ".join(z))
        print("account balance ",accbal)

        #sheet['D2']= (", ".join(z))


   # Retriving Address details
addlines=[]
totalline=0
dearwordline=0
fstnameline=0
index=0
account_index=0
add_index=0


for y in text:
    if "Page 1 of " in y:
        fstnameline=index
        print("fstnameline ",fstnameline)
        break
    index+=1
for z in text:
    if "personal projection:" in z:
        dearwordline=totalline
        print("dearwordline",dearwordline)
        print("totalline",totalline)
    totalline+=1
for cell in sheet["C"]:
    if cell.value is None:
            sheet.cell(column= 2, row=cell.row+account_index, value= name)
            sheet.cell(column= 4, row=cell.row+account_index, value= accbal)
            sheet.cell(column= 1, row=cell.row+account_index, value= accno)
            account_index = dearwordline-fstnameline+1
            #account_name+=account_index
            break
for cell in sheet["C"]:
    if cell.value is None:
        for x in text[fstnameline+1:dearwordline]:
            if add_index < dearwordline-fstnameline-1 :
                if add_index <= cell.row :
                    x.strip()
                    x= x.replace("Could you pay less?","")
                    x= x.replace(",",";")
                    print("x in text:",x)
                    print("cell.row in C : ",cell.row)
                    x= x.replace(" Over the next 12 months","")
                    sheet.cell(row = cell.row, column =3,value = x)
                    print("x after printing in excel:",x)
                    #if cell.row == 7:
                        #print(cell.row,"+" , add_index)
                    cell.row+=1
    #                add_index = dearwordline-fstnameline-1
                    add_index+=1


    #sheet.cell(row = i, column =3).value = x
    #add = x(i) 
    #i+=1

"""for cell in ws["C"]:
    if cell.value is text[fstnameline+1:dearwordline]:
        print("cell row for A,B,D : ",cell.row)
       # ws.cell(column= 1, row=cell.row, value= accno)
        ws.cell(column= 2, row=cell.row, value= name)
        ws.cell(column= 4, row=cell.row, value= accbal)
        i= cell.row
        print (i)
            #break
        #for cell in ws["C"]:
         #   if cell.value is None:
            #ws.cell(row = cell.row, column =3,value = x)
                #ws.cell(column= 3, row=cell.row, value= x)
        cell.row+=1 
        print("cell.row",cell.row)
        print("x in C column ",x)
            #break"""


   # print (add)




    #Writing address to excel
    #sheet.cell(row = i, column =3).value = x
    #i+=1       


        #sheet['Ai'] = int(y)


book.save(r'C:\Users\xxx\Desktop\yy files\test_value.xlsx')**
```

**

Could anyone please help??
I am unable to do anything about it. 
I have only basic knowledge of python. This code is working strange when I am trying to write value in new excel file, it is not going inside the loop itself.
And it is not writing the values in excel.

After running the python script, i am getting excel recovery error as below:
[Excel Recovery Pop up](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Azv87.png)
[Excel Recovery Pop up 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wdxlh.png)

Sorry for the image links, as Stackoverflow site is not allowing me to insert images. So please anyone help me out.

Comment: I don't understand the issue. Is your program not writing to excel file at all, or is it not writing in expected format?

Comment: The client has sent an excel file, where I am supposed to write. When i run the python script to write the value in excel, it is writing in the client sent file. But when I created a new excel file with the same format and ran the python script, it is not going beyond the below code:
`for cell in range["C"]:
if cell.value is None:
            sheet.cell(column= 2, row=cell.row+account_index, value= name)`
IDK if it is the excel corruption error which is why it is not printing properly in excel file.

Comment: *" I created a new excel ... it is not going beyond the for cell in range["C"]"*: A new Sheet does not have a `range['C']`.

Comment: sorry for my mistake, it is as below:
`for cell in sheet["C"]: 
    if cell.value is None: 
            sheet.cell(column= 2, row=cell.row+account_index, value= name)`
This is where it is getting stuck. And I created a excel file first in a folder, saved it and then ran the python script for the existing excel file.